# Pinging Domain replies old A record

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I am having an issue where I ping my domain and it replies back the old IP/A record of that domain. I have checked my Dns records for both NS servers and all records are correct. If I have posted this in the wrong thread please let me know.

Comment: How old is the record? Your client may have cached the DNS entry. Also, new records may not have propagated fully yet.

Comment: We changed the records to the new IP address 5 days ago.

Comment: Is this a linux or windows client? I would like to check using the actual name server. Windows->Run->CMD: nslookup [enter] server 1.2.3.4 (replace with either ns IP) [enter] domain.com [enter] and it should return a result. Is this the new IP or old IP?

Comment: It is a windows server. I'll try that real quick.

Comment: it is telling me that server: unknown address: fe80::7512:acc0: etc. Then DNS request timeout.

Comment: What's the domain?

Comment: Cybsolutions.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible reasons and you gave very little details. We do not even have the domain name to test.

Among the possible reasons:

- You forgot to increment the serial number so the slaves still have the old zone ('dig @slaveserver SOA domainname' to test)
- you have glue records at the registry with the old address ('dig @registryserver A name' to test)

Without more details, we can only guess. For instance, what does "I have checked my Dns records for both NS servers and all records are correct" mean? Did you just read the zone files or tested the actual live DNS server with dig or drill?

Comment: I have simply checked the zone files. This is what I meant. The domain is Cybsolutions.com.

Answer (score 1):

After using dig we found that the DNS of our internal server which we all connect to through a local domain was not updated and using the old IP/A record.

Comment: Edit the question, do not add details as answers.

Comment: This in itself is an answer due to it solved the problem.